# SCNPhysicsShape with SCNTube as geometry causing balls to stop moving

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a node with a SCNTube as its physics body and another set of nodes that cover the tube on top and bottom with SCNPlanes. Whenever a ball collides with the tube they lose most of the energy they had. If they hit the top or bottom they bounce off no problem. The balls have friction, dampening, etc. set to 0 and restitution set to 1. I tried setting the different physics values(friction, restitution, etc.) of the tubes to no effect. The planes are using the default values.